# Display Banner over Plaid-Link in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, plaid

I'm currently working on a webpage in react.js that lets a user link their information via plaid link. However, due to the fact that not all providers are currently available to link through plaid. I want to display a banner at the bottom of the link module that can send the user to a page where they can manually enter the information.
[Heres a mockup of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChgWy.png)

Things I've tried:

- Placing in a bootstraps overlay
- Placing in a bootstrap Modal popup
- Placing in a React DOM portal
- Having an HTML element appear above by having a high z-index when plaid is opened.
- calling the `this.linkhandler.open()` function in a bootstrap modal and react DOM portal

How plaid link is setup on the Page:

```
onScriptLoaded(){
   this.linkHandler = window.Plaid.Create({
      apiVersion:"v2",
      clientName: clientName,
      countryCodes: this.state.countryCodes,
      env: environment,
      key: key,
      onExit: this.handleOnExit,
      onLoad: this.handleLinkOnLoad,
      onSuccess: this.handleOnSuccess,
      product: this.state.products,
      selectAccount: false,
      token: this.state.token,
      webhook:this.state.webhook,
      accountSubtypes:this.state.subtypes,
   });
   this.setState({disabledButton:false});
}

handleLinkOnLoad() {
   this.setState({ linkLoaded: true });
}

handleOnClick(event) {
   if (this.linkHandler) {
      this.linkHandler.open();
      this.setState({linkOpened:true});
   }
}

handleOnExit() {
    // handles exit
}

handleOnSuccess() {
   // handles Success
}

render() {
   return(
      <div>
         <Button onClick={this.handleOnClick} disabled={this.state.disabledButton}>
            link your info
         </Button>
         <Script
              url="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"
              onError={this.onScriptError}
              onLoad={this.onScriptLoaded}>
          </Script>
      </div>
   )

}
```

Note, while this is implemented in the same way as the `react-plaid-link` module I'm not importing the module in this page because it currently doesn't support the `accountSubtypes` parameter which I needed